# Reversing animateWithDuration

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

I have an animation that runs forward from an IBAction. On the next IBAction I would like it to reverse. I see that animateWithDuration had an autoreverse function but I only want it to go one way each time.

I have figured a workaround by simply loading a reverse array into the view but I am wondering if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a state to the animation as an `ivar` in your object which is invoking the animation.

Either as a `BOOL` or `NSInteger` . An integer would allow more than two states.

e.g

```
BOOL animationState;

-(IBAction)actionWhichTriggers:(id)sender
{

if(animationState)
{
    animationState = NO;
    [self reverseAnimateMechanism];
}
else
{
   animationState = YES;
   [self forwardAnimateMechanism];
}


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Good question!
Some animations has they counterpart: like rotating. Those has more elegant method.